# Ubuntu on Mac for dummies?

Tags: installation, wubi, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi Install for Mac OS X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6505/wubi-install-for-mac-os-x)

I like Ubuntu on my PC but I tried many times to install on Mac in vain. It is too complicated and too many technical stuff for me. I like to see easy install on Mac,like Wubi. Is there anyway around to painlessly install Linux on Mac?